# accessing File within directory and subdirectory giving me error -- URI formats are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, filesystems

I am trying to get files in Directory and subdirectory from a webpage. I don't know if this is the right Idea i am using. If not can any one please give me an idea how to access files and folder on an ip address that is on apache server.

The code below is giving me "URI formats are not supported." error.

I dont want to use local directory as i have to access file from that address (apache server)

```
public static DataTable search_method(string searchkeyword)
    {
        string path = "http://192.168.2.10/mywebsite/";
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        Table.Columns.Add("AnchorText");
        Table.Columns.Add("dt");
        DataRow dr = null;
       foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (file.Contains(searchkeyword))
            {
                    string AnchorText = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                    DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
                    dr = Table.NewRow();
                    dr[1] = AnchorText;
                    dr[2] = dt;
                    Table.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
        }
        return Table;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what is wrong, and that you can't do this.

If you look at the [Directory.GetFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you see that the first parameter is *path*, which is *The directory to search*. The directory is a path on your server, not a URI, hence, `URI formats are not supported`. You can use this to search directories on your server, not someone else's webserver that you can only access via URL.

You can make requests to webservers using [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but that would be similar to viewing a page in a browser, not like searching directories in `GetFiles`.

You won't be able to view a list of the files in a directory on a webserver unless they have allowed it. If they have, then try [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: but i want to search that URI, how can i do it

Comment: does the webserver allow for directory listings?

Comment: it doesnot, can i access files any other way to provide login details. this machine that i am accessing is LINUX

Comment: @user3202862 if they don't allow directory browsing, and you can't map a drive, then I think you'd be stuck essentially crawling the site.

Comment: can you please tell me what changes do they need on apache server that can enable me to access the direcotries and how can i do this.